# HtmlUnitDriver browser emulate mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I have created a simple factory method that creates a HtmlUnitDriver in a specified mode. For example

```
public static HtmlUnitDriver createHtmlUnitDriver(String browserMode) {
    switch(browserMode.toLowerCase()) {
        case "chrome":
            return new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        case "firefox":
            return new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
        case "ie":
        case "internet explorer":
            return new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
        case default:
            return new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    }
}
```

I'd like to write a quick unit test of this method, but I can't see how to tell which "mode" the returned `HtmlUnitDriver` is in. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reflection, you can get the private field `webClient`

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    WebClient webClient = (WebClient) get(driver, "webClient");
    System.out.println(webClient.getBrowserVersion());
    System.out.println(webClient.getBrowserVersion().isIE());
    driver.close();
}

private static Object get(Object object, String field) throws Exception {
    Field f = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return f.get(object);
}
```